Использование ARRAYFORMULA
дано 2 листа в гугл таблицах:
1 Лист

столбец B содержит артикулы товаров
столбец F - должен содержать кол-во товаров на складе "fbo"

2 Лист содержит

столбец F - артикул товара
столбец W - кол-во товара
столбец AB тип склада fbo или fbs

Нужно отобразить на первом листе кол-во товара по артикулу только из склада fbo. Если возвращает 0 - оставляем поле пустым.
Есть формула:
=ЕСЛИ(СУММЕСЛИМН('Лист2'!W:W; 'Лист2'!AB:AB; "fbo"; 'Лист2'!F:F; B2) = 0; ""; СУММЕСЛИМН('Лист2'!W:W; 'Лист2'!AB:AB; "fbo"; 'Лист2'!F:F; B2))

Но задача использовать массив, чтобы не протягивать каждый раз формулу.
при использовании ArrayFormula в заголовке - заполняется только следующая ячейка и все.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

приведите пример вашей таблицы


Если возвращает 0 - оставляем поле пустым* - не очень хорошая мысль, если в дальнейшем диапазон будет использоваться для вычислений. Если в ячейке формула - значит, и значение есть. И "пусто" - это не пустая ячейка. Она содержит текст нулевой длины. А наличие текстов в диапазоне с числовыми данными может добавить головной боли в будущем.


Да, да... В огороде пусто - выросла капуста. А в Excel, кстати, если режим без отображения нулей. А в этой беде есть такое? Если есть, то может подойдёт?

Попробуйте
=map(B2:B4;lambda(x;ЕСЛИ(СУММЕСЛИМН('Лист2'!G:G; 'Лист2'!H:H; "fbo"; 'Лист2'!F:F; x) = 0; ""; СУММЕСЛИМН('Лист2'!G:G; 'Лист2'!H:H; "fbo"; 'Лист2'!F:F; x))))

где в B2:B4 укажите последнюю строчку вместо 4.

Пусто добавите сами, если захотите.

Если мой ответ помог, то вы можете отметить его как принятый.
